# Hosting 2 different servers with 2 different IPs on same network

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have two Minecraft servers that I've set up on my MacBook and my PC. Both are using No-IP, and the server on the MacBook is under 2xedo.ddns.net, while the other is tux3do.ddns.net. I've set different static internal IPs for each device, but both have the same external IP, as they're on the same network. Thus I can only put one external IP for both the hosts in No-IP. This leads to both IPs connected to the same server, and I need to modify both freely of each other.

How can I basically make it so the different No-IP hostnames connect to the different servers? I've forwarded two ports, 25565 and 25570, but using (my external ip):25570 results in `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information:` Could I possibly make each hostname access a different internal IP after the external IP?

(This is somewhat specific to No-IP and DDNS, I'm going to ask this question on their forums.)

Answer (score 1):

If you forwarded 25565 to one internal IP and 25570 to the other, then you can connect to either host with the correct port to get to the server you want.

You cannot do anything with a hostname to go to a specific port, so there is no way to have each No-IP host go directly to the proper server.

Comment: *"there is no way to have each No-IP host go directly to the proper server"* - that is incorrect.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I was actually thinking of getting something like that but I didn't know what it was called, thanks :^)